# Можно ли в перемнной "подлючение к серверу" не указывать название базы даних?

Tags: c#

Я хочу создать в SQL Server Management Studio базу даных через код программы, где я "прописываю" комманду для создания новой базы даных:

```
    CREATE DATABASE [{0}]
    CONTAINMENT = NONE
    ON  PRIMARY
    ( NAME = N'{0}', FILENAME = N'C:\Temp\{0}.mdf' , SIZE = 5120KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
    LOG ON
    ( NAME = N'{0}_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Temp\{0}_log.ldf' , SIZE = 13312KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
    GO
    ALTER DATABASE [{0}] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
    GO
    ALTER DATABASE [{0}] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
    GO
    ALTER DATABASE [{0}] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
    GO
    ALTER DATABASE [{0}] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
    GO
    USE [{0}]
    GO
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.filegroups WHERE is_default=1 AND name = N'PRIMARY') ALTER DATABASE [{0}] MODIFY FILEGROUP [PRIMARY] DEFAULT
    GO
```

Можно ли в нижеуказанной переменной, где дефинируется сервер, к которому я хочу подключиться, не указывать  имя базы даных (так, как ее практически еще не существует) и создать нову базу даных или это делается как-то по другому?

```
  String sqlConnectionString = "Server = AMASNMSSQL01; Database =    Test_database; Trusted_Connection = True;";
```

Comment: [Аналогичный вопрос на enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24600076/2076787), можно сделать перевод ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, нельзя - но вы можете подключиться к БД, которая заведомо существует. Например, `master`.